# Responsive view website checking

Tags: html, css

I am creating responsive view website. I want to test my webpage into iphone and ipad. If any online website available to check my responsive view page?

Thanks

Comment: You should [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=responsive+online&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) first before asking questions here

Comment: http://sixrevisions.com/tools/10-excellent-tools-for-testing-your-site-on-mobile-devices/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres quite a few:

http://www.responsinator.com/

http://www.websitedimensions.com/sitegrid/index.php

http://mattkersley.com/responsive/

But try googleing before asking questions like Mr Alien said

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mozilla and chrome for responsive design.

Mozilla : Ctrl+shift+M for Mozilla

Chrome : F12 key and click on right side on the bottom setting icon click on overrides
and checked the user agent according to device resolution.

also download the Mozilla developer tool :-

http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

Answer (score 0):

Try [screenqueries](http://screenqueri.es/)

I personally use this website. As I used a lot of sites like ipadpeek, etc, but when I check in my iPhone and iPad, the replica of what I want to see is very different from what I see on the supposed iPad/iPhone sites than what I see actually on my device. Then I came across the screenqueries website and it has given me a near 90%-95% replica of what I actually see on my iPhone or iPad. Great resource.